# having problem accessing laravel homestead project via udemylaravel.app but 192.168.10.10 is working well

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am new in laravel. I have installed homestead 10.0.0. and successfully created a project.

I am facing a problem accessing my laravel project website via typing custom web address for the website "udemylaravel.app" but if I enter 192.168.10.10 I can access the website.

here is my configuration of nano /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       laravel-udemy   laravel-udemy

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#### HOMESTEAD-SITES-BEGIN
192.168.10.10   udemylaravel.app
#### HOMESTEAD-SITES-END
# Laravel
192.168.10.10   udemylaravel.app
```

And here is my homestead.yaml file

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: 'C:\Users\S\laravel-udemy'
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: udemylaravel.app
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
databases:
    - homestead
features:
    -
        mariadb: false
    -
        ohmyzsh: false
    -
        webdriver: false
name: laravel-udemy
hostname: laravel-udemy
```

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no homestead laravel expart wants to help. sad

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine. Try `vagrant reload --provision` to update the Nginx configuration on the virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you. But the solution is not working. problem persists.